# Random function stuck on one number

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main (){

int guess, maxGuess = 10; 
int goal = rand()%50+1;

for (int i = 0 ; i<maxGuess;i++){
printf("Enter a guess between 1-50:\n");
scanf("%d",&guess); 

if (guess<goal){
    printf("Too low\n");
}
else if(guess>goal){
printf("Too high\n"); 
}

else if (guess == goal){
printf("Correct! the number was %d\n",goal); 
}

}
//printf("Too many guesses, the number was %d\n",goal);  

return 0; 
}
```

this my code for a guessing game , and when it runs through it will give me the same number , for example when compiled it kept giving me 34 ,the random number kept generating 34.  I cannot seem to find what I did wrong , maybe i have something in the wrong place I am not to sure I commented out the last line to see if it would help but did not, but I have looked and I haven't found anything really similar to my question so any help is appreciated!

TIA

Comment: If you don't call [`srand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand) and provide it with a seed value, the program uses the default seed of 1. If you want different numbers every time you execute the program, each execution needs to use a different seed. People often use the current time as the seed since that's a reasonable value that usually changes between program invocations.

Comment: i added in the srand and  i still got 34, maybe i am adding it in incorrectly?

Comment: OT: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values)  to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when the value is correctly guessed,  after the call to `printf()` insert a `break;` statement so the program exits the `for()` loop rather than requiring the user to input all 10 guesses.

Comment: i will add that in! thanks

Comment: regarding: `printf("Enter a guess between 1-50:\n");`  the value returned from the call to `rand()`  will return a value in the range 0...50.  Suggest modifying `int goal = rand()%50+1;` to `int goal = 1 + rand()%50;` which will return a value in the range 1...50

Comment: I think they wanted it to be between 0 and 50

Answer (score 2):

You never seed the random number generator.

If `rand` is called before calling `srand`, the random number generator is seeded with 1.  So you get the same number every time.

Call `srand` once at the start of your program to seed the random number generator.

```
srand(time(NULL));
int goal = rand()%50+1;
```

Comment: do i need to import another library for it? i have seen srand used before and others have imported the time library

Comment: @Breanna You need to `#include <time.h>` for the `time` function.

Comment: Sorry that was my fault , it worked for me , thanks again!

Comment: @Breanna Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.